# Rails date without year

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

How can I find a record by date, but without the year?

this is what I have :

```
@date = Date.today
@article = Article.find_by_date(@date)
```

But really what I wanna do is search for an article that by only the month and the day.  The year is not important.

Answer (score 2):

Tested with SQLite:

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["STRFTIME('%m-%d', field_name) = '?-?'", 12, 25])
```

The generated query illustrates how this finds everything where `field_name` is Christmas:

```
Model Load (16.1ms)  SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE (STRFTIME('%m-%d', field_name) = '12-25')
```

I also had success with the shorter "field_name LIKE '%-MM-DD'" but this was MySQL; according to its manual, it indeed uses strings to read and write dates. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is dependent on which database you're using. Different implementations have different names/syntax for the EXTRACT or DATE_PART function. On PostgreSQL, this one works:

```
Model.where('EXTRACT(month FROM field_name) = ? AND EXTRACT(day FROM field_name) = ?', 12, 25)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Model.all.where(["DAY(`date`) = ? AND MONTH(`date`) = ?", Date.current., 12])
```

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

A DB agnostic approach would be to add attributes to your model for date_month and date_day (and set them with a before_save callback). Something like:

```
before_save :set_date_day_and_month

def set_date_day_and_month
  self.date_month = date.month
  self.date_day = date.day
end
#untested
```

Then you can do straight-forward queries that wouldn't involve db-specific functions. Like:

```
Article.where('date_month = ? AND date_day = ?', 12, 25)
#for articles on Christmas
```

Or:

```
Article.where('date_month = ? AND date_day = ?', Date.today.month, Date.today.day)
#for articles on this date any year
```